# Upgrading magento2 installation with fresh install, outdated modules warning

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I'm a little stuck when i started om my project i cloned the Magento2 dev repo instead of composer or manual instal..

Now i want to sort this out since my project is almost going live but still on 2.0.0. When i create a clean install i get the following error

```
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Theme schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Theme data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Customer schema: current version - 2.0.7, required version - 2.0.6
Magento_Customer data: current version - 2.0.7, required version - 2.0.6
Magento_Cms schema: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
Magento_Cms data: current version - 2.0.1, required version - 2.0.0
.....
```

This is just een excerpt many more modules.. 
Am i mising something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Problem is, that the database has newer Versions of the Schema then your actual modules have.

The Theme Module for example. In your Database, 2.0.1 is installed while your code is 2.0.0.

Since 2.0.0 is the current version in the [2.0](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Theme/etc/module.xml) branch and 2.0.1 the current version in the [develop](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/etc/module.xml) branch it seems like you cloned Magento2 and checked out the develop branch, installed it and then checked out the 2.0 branch (or maybe the 2.0.6 Tag for example)

Since there is no downgrade functionality I think you have to reinstall Magento from the correct source code Version.

Comment: Thats actually what I did. I think it's a little bit the way around. I installed now the correct one. But since my database is coming from the develop branch my db is 2.0.1 while the code is 2.0.0. Is there a way of just changing values in the db. Or will that screw up things very badly?

Comment: the problem is that the install scripts for the newer versions already ran and altered your database. It is possible to change the values in the setup_module table. It's very likely to cause unpredictable behaviour since your code relies on a different db schema. Also it will break if you later really want to upgrade your magento instance, because the update scripts already ran but due to the manipulation in the table will be executed again

Comment: Do you suggest to fresh install export import products and configurations?

Comment: yes I think this would be the best solution for you

Comment: you could also think about  export -> import complete tables if you compare them first and they have the same structure (for tables that are not covered by the magento import/export module)

Comment: Hmm going to be the last option i think. We already have 100+ static blocks pages and so on...

Comment: there are only a few tables for cms pages + blocks (I think 4?). It should be possible do copy the tables quite easy. you can also go through all updated modules and revert all changes to the database manually, but honestly, I'm pretty sure that this is much more work